# how to use {% block body %} and {% endblock %} without django?

Tags: html, css, web

I know that in django, you can use {% block body %} and {% endblock %} to extend your html so that you won't have to repeat "repeating-syntax" such as the navbar and the footer. However, I'm currently doing a very simple landing static multiple-pages which doesn't require django. So what can i use in order to not repeat my codes in multiple htmls?

Sorry im still a beginner in web development. Any help would be appreciated thank you so much.

Comment: You can use JavaScript to do so, but this question is a bit too broad. Please post your codes.

Comment: There are literally dozens of template frameworks that can be used. You can try everything from to jQuery to Underscore to Handlebars. Choose one which has similar syntax to that which you know to make it easier to understand.